# Print user group name with Auth::User()->user_group->name in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, model, echo

I'm trying to display the user group name in a view using Auth::user()->user_group->name, but apparently that doesn't work as I keep getting Trying to get property of non-object.

The code goes as follow

User_Group.php Model

```
<?php

class User_Group extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'user_groups';

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }

}
```

User.php Model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function user_group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User_Group', 'user_groups_id');
    }

    public function getGravatarAttribute()
    {
        $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($this->attributes['email'])));
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash?s=100";
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->user_groups_id == 1;
    }

}
```

My profile.blade.php view

```
<small><p class="pull-right">{{ Auth::user()->user_group->name }}</p></small>
```

Doing the following will print the user group id reference though:

```
 {{ Auth::user()->user_groups_id }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the method to group instead of user_group

Comment: Well that did the trick... but why? Does it not support using underscores?

Comment: I honestly have no damn clue, I've had this issue before, it must be some kind of a naming convention thing

Comment: Gotcha! Greatly appreciated!